# eclipse Syntax error, insert “}” to complete classbody

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android programming. I am getting only one error saying `insert } to complete class body` and it is showing in the line depicted by arrow as below. Please can anyone help me in this regard.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button submit;
String temp;
DatePicker dt;
int day,month,year,choice;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton()
{
submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
dt=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{                               //<--------------------here
public void onClick(View v)
{
day=dt.getDayOfMonth();
month=dt.getMonth();
year=dt.getYear();
choice=(day+month+year) % 5;
switch (choice)
{
................
................
}
Toast t= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are"+temp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
}
});
}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code, it's not easy to read as it is, especially finding missing }...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a `{` instead of a `}` ? Are you about to close the method `addListenerOnButton` ?

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button submit;
String temp;
DatePicker dt;
int day,month,year,choice;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton()
{
submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
dt=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()//add View method
{                               //<--------------------here
public void onClick(View v)
{
day=dt.getDayOfMonth();
month=dt.getMonth();
year=dt.getYear();
choice=(day+month+year) % 5;
switch (choice)
{
................
................
}
Toast t= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are"+temp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
}
});
}
}
```

Add View.OnclickListener describe in my code.

Comment: I have checked your code in my eclipse editor. And there is no syntax error. Just check all the code over there within switch block.